# FirstOrDefault giving different results on different computers when comparing DateTime? objects

Tags: c#, datetime, iqueryable

I am trying to compare two nullable DateTime objects (that are brought from a database) within an IQueryable as follows:

```
result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstDateTime == secondDateTime)
```

This executes properly on some developers' computers, but it doesn't on mine. It gives no results. because if I convert the result to a list like this, it works:

```
result.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstDateTime == secondDateTime)
```

Of course I wouldn't like to leave the code like that, it's just to show that it is not because the date cannot be found in the IQueryable

Both values are UTC. I tried using `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, and `Where` all with the same results. I have also tried comparing `FirstDateTime.Value` with `secondDateTime.Value`. Again, same result

The provider for the IQueryable is

> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.

What could be causing this? How come the first segment works on some computers, but doesn't on others, what could it depend on?

This is the SQL that is being generated :

```
FROM ( SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[OtherProperty1] AS [OtherProperty1], 
[Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
[Extent1].[Submitted] AS [Submitted], 
[Extent1].[SubmittedBy] AS [SubmittedBy], 
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Extent2].[Value] AS [Value], 
[Extent2].[OtherProperty2] AS [OtherProperty2], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent2].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], 
[Extent2].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], 
[Extent2].[OtherProperty3] AS [OtherProperty3], 
[Extent2].[OtherProperty4] AS [OtherProperty4], 
[Extent2].[FirstDateTime] AS [FirstDateTime], 
''0X0X'' AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[StructuredInformations] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Positions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE ([Extent1].[OtherProperty1] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].
[FirstDateTime] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[FirstDateTime] = @p__linq__1)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[OtherProperty2] DESC, [Project1].[FirstDateTime] ASC,    
[Project1].[Value] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1  
datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0=7,@p__linq__1='2016-10-11 11:45:53.6230000'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125927/discussion-on-question-by-robert-firstordefault-giving-different-results-on-diff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204759/linq-entity-framework-4-2-datetime-comparison-fails) - looks like the LINQ provider generated a datetime value with a fractional second precision of 7 (e.g. 2016-10-11 11:45:53.6230000) while the column in SQL is defined as [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), which has a precision lower than 7, as opposed to [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) which can have a precision of up to 7

To work around this, you can change the column type in SQL from datetime to datetime(7)

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable` does not guarantee ordering. `List<T>` does. to keep `IQueryable` and maintain order you should try to sort `IQueryable` and than try to get first result:

```
result.OrderBy(y => y.FirstDateTime).FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstDateTime == secondDateTime)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it's not the order that is wrong, but that it returns no data

Comment: i saw your update. without it i tought that it return different values, not any value at all